# What is Khadgar saying?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am level 90.

In the blasted lands I met Khadgar and he said "Are you prepared to face whatever's on the other side of the portal?" and I felt that I was ready, after that I have a choice to embark on a dangerous mission, I want to go but there is a warning about not being able to return immediately.

What exactly can I not return to?

Comment: Just go, it's relatively quick.

Comment: @Thebluefish are you suggesting that the mission is a short one, and whatever it is you "cannot return to" will be accessible again one you have finished?

Comment: Pretty sure he is. It's about 45-60 minutes of play time (or it was for me; dependent on lag and how much quest text you read) from when you accept until you get the garrison hearthstone. That's really the first time you can reliably get back to Draenor if you leave.

Comment: @ben sorry for the late reply, yes that's what I meant. After roughly an hour, he will be able to go back. I've been so busy leveling my characters that I forgot to stop by gaming.SE for a few days xD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What exactly can I not return to?

Azeroth. What he's talking about is that after you cross through the Dark Portal, you have to play through a (roughly hour-long) introductory quest chain before you can leave. Shortly after you complete the intro sequence, you should acquire the means to return to Azeroth.